# INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, binding does not work

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-7, inotifypropertychanged

I'm learning to create an app for WP7 (Mango), and somehow having this problem.
This is not actual code to my app, but a simplified version of the same problem. I think mostly it's due to lack of deep understanding of how binding works.

XAML.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
```

Code Behind.

```
private MainPageViewModel viewModel;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.GenerateTitle();
    }
```

And my ViewModel.

```
        private static int counter = 0;

    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            if (title != value)
            {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        title = "Init";
    }

    public void GenerateTitle()
    {
        if (counter == 0)
            title = "0"; // Title = "0" will work fine.
        if (counter == 1)
            title = "1";

        counter++;
    }
```

Problem is, it only update the binding once inside my ViewModel constructor, so the title is "Init".

Any call to the GenerateTitle does not update the property. It works if I use 'Title' instead of 'title', which calls the setter.

Or I should really use 'Title'? I haven't done much C#, so my understanding of OOP is not that great yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line in the setter is what notifies the observers that he value has changed:

```
OnPropertyChanged("Title");
```

When you use the private field value, that method isn't being called so the observers aren't being notified that the value of the property has changed.

Because of that, you need to use the Property if you want the observers to be notified. You could also add the `OnPropertyChanged("Title");` line to your `GenerateTitle()` method, but I would recommend just using the Property.

Comment: Thank you. But for the purpose of understanding this problem, what's the use of the private field `title` except for backing up the property `Title`? For general rule of thumb, would you use any property inside the class that defines it? I thought public property should just be used to access outside the class, and use field for anything inside. Thanks again.

Comment: The title field provides the backing store for the property. In .NET a property is a formalised pair of methods that syntactically look like accessing a public field but under the covers methods are executed. The state that the methods manipulate has to be stored somewhere - that's what title is. Title is the definition of the methods. Inside the class you use the construct that gives you the effect you need. If you want to make a change without raising a notification change the field. If you want to make a change that raises the notification use the property

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to use Title as title just sets the field whereas Title runs the setter which raises the event